# Why equipotential surface for an electric dipole is concentric oval shells around the opposite charges?

Tags: electrostatics, dipole

[image]Why equipotential surface for an electric dipole is concentric oval shells around the opposite charges? Please explain.

Comment: For the $V=0$ isoline, check out [Apollonian circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles), which is useful for the method of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potentials of the two charges are summed together at every point in space. This will naturally create a bias as the closer you look to the positive charge, the greater the potential will be, and the closer you look to the negative charge, the lower the potential will be.

Each individual charge provides a electric potential of:

$$V=\frac{\pm q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r}$$

So we then find for any given point in space, the net electric potential is:

$$V=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r_{+}}-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r_{-}}$$

$$V=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}(r_{+}^{-1}-r_{-}^{-1})$$

Where $r_{+}$ is the distance to the positive charge and $r_{-}$ is the distance to the negative charge.

The lines of equipotential then connect every point for which $V$ is the same.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a little on how is the shape oval? By using values of electric field intensity and potential at different points. Pls explain in this way once.

Comment: @SukritiSharma I made some additions to my answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three images produced by the Wolfram Demonstrations Project [Potential Field of Two Charges](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/demonstrations/PotentialFieldOfTwoCharges-source.nb) of the equipotential lines produced by two charges.
One is always $+1$ unit and the other varies between $-1$ and $-3$.

[image]

Unfortunately a single charge potential diagram was not available but if it had been then the equipotential lines would have been concentric circles centred on the charge.
The other thing missing is labels in volts for each of the equipotential lines.

Be that as in may, you will note that as magnitude of one charge is increased it begins to dominate the equipotential plot and the equipotentials no longer look *oval*.

Also, remembering that these plots are akin to plotting contour lines of constant height on a geographical map, the magnitude of the potential gradient between increase as the magnitude of the negative electric charge increase which is consistent with the strength of the electric charge between the two charges increasing.

You might see what happens when the separation of the charges is changed.

[image]

If you use WolframAlpha and enter [two charges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=two+charges) the force between two charges is calculated but also at the bottom of the page there is and electric field and equipotential plot which might be of interest?
In particular have a look at the plots when the charges are of opposite sign and differ in magnitude by factors of $5$ and $10$.

Comment: thanks....the graphical representation actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

The oval shape of level curves(or equipotential surfaces)in between opposite charges is attributed to the fact that electric field intensity is of higher value than the region before the positive or the region after the negative charges.
By definition,Electric field intensity is gradient of scalar potential field.
$$\vec{E}=\nabla.V$$
$$\vec{E}=\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}}\hat{i}+\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{y}}\hat{j}+\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{z}}\hat{k}$$
Or simply
$$\vec{E}=\frac{dV}{dr}\hat{r}$$
The electric field between two charges is of higher value. It also means the gradient of potential between charges is more. Due to this, for finite change in potential, change in spacing between surfaces is less.
It follows the simple relation
$$|\vec{E}|\propto\frac{1}{\Delta{r}}$$
$$where\;\Delta{V}\;is\;constant.$$
Therefore, the spacing between surfaces is less on the interior side causing the surface to be oval in shape.

Comment: Due to this, for finite change in potential, change in spacing between surfaces is less. It follows the simple relation
E inversely proportional to change in r
whereΔVis constant.
Therefore, the spacing between surfaces is less on the interior side causing the surface to be oval in shape.......can you please explain how does the relation between electric field intensity and change in r tells us that the equipotential lines on the inner side have less space between them provided change in potential is constant.

Comment: Electric field intensity takes higher values between changes. It simply means the potential between charges decrease more rapidly. In order to account for that we must have closely spaced surfaces.